# Change image src based on style width + height

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net mvc project, and a function that streams out an image based on url parameters. like: /Image/40/100/50 streams out image with ImageID 40, 100px wide and 50px high.

So is there a way to change:

```
<img class="image" src="/Content/View?fileID=31" style="width: 500px; height: 100px; " />
```

To:

```
<img class="image" src="/Image/31/500/100" style="width: 500px; height: 100px; " />
```

In some fancy way?
/Lasse

Comment: Be certain that the browser will load the original image in every case! So if you want to scale the images to save bandwidth, this is not the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you're trying to do this, but something along the lines of the following should do the trick:

```
$("img[src^='/Content/View?fileID=']").each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    var id = img.attr("src").substring(21);
    img.attr("src", "/Image/" + id + "/" + img.width().toString() + "/" + img.height().toString());
});
```

Link to example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cfdfp/2/

Also, if you're only applying the `image` class to img elements that require this transformation, you could simplify the selector above:

```
$(".image").each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    var id = img.attr("src").substring(21);
    img.attr("src", "/Image/" + id + "/" + img.width().toString() + "/" + img.height().toString());
});
```

Link to example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cfdfp/1/

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr('src').substr($this.attr('src').indexOf('=')+1),
        wid = $this.width(),
        hgt = $this.height();
    $this.attr('src','/Image/'+id+'/'+wid+'/'+hgt);
});
```

Comment: Why using `$this.attr('width')` instead of `$this.width()`? He wants to respect the css width value, not the attribute _width_.